# Calculate maximum Capacity of a REST-Endpoint?

Tags: java, rest, api, jmeter

I want to calculate the maximum Connections/Users/Requests a REST-Endpoint can handle in a Second (with Jmeter).

My first idea was to use a Variable Amount of Threads (users) and ramp that number up over time until the Result is Wrong or the Latency is to high.

```
Maximum-Capaticy =  ( numberOf(First-Sampler-that-failed) - 1)
```

But the Problem is if i use 2 Threads/Users i can hit the Server (obv.) 247
but if i use 80T at a Time the Second Thread/Sampler is Already failing so this approach doesnt work.

What is the correct way to calculate maximum capacity? Is there maybe a formula or something? I can't find any information on this Topic.

**Update**: should I maybe just ramp up slower?

For example: run `N` threads for

```
(maximumResponseTime [ms] * (10000 [ms] + N * 1000))
```

and increment `N += 10` every iteration? The advantage should be that the threads increment slower and if they fail there should be a margin of error of ~10?

Comment: There are lot of factors you need to count in, I would start with same network env. as production as well as production computing resources (memory cpu etc...) will be the most realistic thing you need. If you just want to know 'your application' facts still you need a good low latency network/hardware setup.

Comment: @HRgiger but how would i get the maximum number of users a endpoint can handle? how do i measure that?